# Remove Usercontrol from panel by itself

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I created a UserControl now I want to use several of these controls in stack panel

```
<StackPanel>
  <local:myUserControl/>
  <local:myUserControl/>
  <local:myUserControl/>
</StackPanel>
```

UserControl has a button that whene the user click on it, UserControl must be removed from the StackPanel.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
   ((Panel) this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
```